# How can I import a JSON into the google maps style editor?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this article: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-customization/map-styles

It says that to import a JSON into the cloud style editor, you select the Import JSON radio button. However, when I go to the styling page, I don't see this button. Where can I go to import a JSON file into the cloud-based style editor?

[Image of what I see in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAC9X.png)

Comment: I can't see that option anymore. I suggest you file a new bug in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).

Comment: FWIW, I have created an issue on the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/323011272